# How to aggregate intraday time stamps and create a new column in pandas dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've tried this problem for hours and has no solution..

Below is intraday 5 min forex data - df. It is recorded every 5 mins every day.
I have excluded weekends data since market is close on weekends.Here a weekend is defined as from Friday 5:00 pm - Sunday 5:00 pm.

```
                   Time             OPEN      CLOSE       
    216    2014-01-01 18:05:00     0.891975  0.892185    
    217    2014-01-01 18:10:00     0.892075  0.892090 
    ...
    210238 2015-12-31 23:55:00     1.000390  1.000390   
    210239 2016-01-01 00:00:00     1.000390  1.000390
```

A day is defined as from 11:00 am - 11:00 am. So when I say 2014-01-02, I am aggregating data from 2014-01-01 11:00 am to 2014-01-02 11:00 am.
2014-01-06(monday) will include data from two intervals:
1. 2014-01-03(friday) 11:00 - 17:00
2. 2014-01-05(sunday) 17:00 - 2014-01-06 11:00

I want to create a new column 'Date' to define the new "day"
so by reading df.Time, the column will record which day it belongs to.

how would you approach this?

```
                   Time             OPEN      CLOSE   Date      
        2014-01-03 14:05:00     0.891975  0.892185    2014-01-06
        2014-01-05 17:00:00     0.892075  0.892090    2014-01-06
        2014-01-06 11:00:00     0.892075  0.892090    2014-01-06
    ...
        2015-12-31 23:55:00     1.000390  1.000390    2016-01-01
        2016-01-01 00:00:00     1.000390  1.000390    2016-01-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use pandas offsets.

```
import pandas as pd

times = pd.date_range('2016-01-01 11:00:00', '2016-01-15 11:00:00', freq='H')
pd.to_datetime((times - pd.offsets.Hour(11) + pd.offsets.BDay()).date)
```

`times` gets every hour between `'2016-01-01 11:00:00'` and `'2016-01-15 11:00:00'`

Based on your description, if I subtract 11 hours and add a business day, I should be on the day you are looking for.  Then I convert to the day without the time component.